# Google Cloud Build gke-deploy could not parse reference "eu.gcr.io/personal-134286/portfolio:6ccad35"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

I have setup a cloud build pipeline [using this guide](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-gke#building_and_deploying_a_new_container_image) but on the last step where it should apply the k8s configuration it gives a non descriptive error:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy
Error: could not parse reference: "eu.gcr.io/personal-134286/portfolio:6ccad35"
```

last step in `cloudbuild.yaml`

```yaml
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy"
  args:
  - run
  - --filename=config/deployment.yaml
  - --image="eu.gcr.io/${_CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_PROJECT_ID}/${_IMAGE_NAME}:$SHORT_SHA"
  - --location=${_CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE}
  - --cluster=${_CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER}
```

spec of `config/deployment.yaml`

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: portfolio
    image: "eu.gcr.io/personal-134286/portfolio"
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "52Mi"
        cpu: "10m"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

I verified that the image exists and if I manually place the image into deployment.yaml and run `kubectl apply` on it it works without a hitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the host of the container registry. After changing from `eu.gcr.io` to `gcr.io` the builds pass.

I opened an [issue in the cloud build repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/739)